# How to create multiple columns with across?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to write the equivalent of this R code in a more synthetic way because in my real example I have a lot of var1, var2 columns.

I thought it would be possible with across?

```
library(dplyr)

price <- tribble(
  ~code, ~var1, ~var2,
  "a", 1, 8,
  "b", 4, 5
)

quant <- tribble(
  ~code, ~var1, ~var2,
  "a", 10, 90,
  "b", 12, 88
)

# what I want to do in a more synthetic way
tab3 <- data.frame(
  code = price$code,
  var1 = price$var1 * quant$var1,
  var2 = price$var2 * quant$var2
)
```

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: sorry, see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can left-join and mutate across the known variables.

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(price, quant, by = "code", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(across(c(var1, var2), ~ . * cur_data()[[paste0(cur_column(), ".y")]])) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"))
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   code   var1  var2
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a        10   720
# 2 b        48   440
```

Explanation:

- `across` only allows us to work on one column at a time, values only
- however, we can get the current column's name with `cur_column()`
- since we are controlling the suffixes of the columns created in the join (using `suffix=`), we know that `var1` and `var2` both have a `.y`-complement
- knowing the other column's *name*, we can use standard `[[` access on `cur_data()`, which is generally the same as the original data coming into the pipe, in full context of grouping, arranging, and other columns recently added to the data within this or previous calls to `mutate`

Answer (score 3):

Another way would to be use `powerjoin`'s `conflict` parameter:

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_inner_join(price, quant, conflict = `*`, by = "code")

#   code var1 var2
# 1    a   10  720
# 2    b   48  440
```

Comment: Oooh, haven't seen that before. Very cool!

Answer (score 3):

Here´s a solution with a little bit of `purrr`. Selection helper `starts_with` gives more control over variables and `reduce`, over the function.
Hope this helps.

```
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")

tab3 <- tibble(
  code = price$code,
  reduce(
    .x = map(list(price, quant), \(x) select(x, starts_with("var"))),
    .f = `*`))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  code   var1  var2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        10   720
2 b        48   440
```

Comment: Nice first contribution! +1

Comment: One can't just only get answers forever. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your rows and columns are in the same order, then multiply the numeric columns in the data frame structure:

```
result = cbind(data.frame(code = price$code), price[-1] * quant[-1])
result
#   code var1 var2
# 1    a   10  720
# 2    b   48  440
```